# Android: TextView.setLayoutParams sometimes work, sometimes doesn't

Tags: java, android

I have an android app that let's the user modify some layout parameters. One of my functions let's the user decide if a TextView will be aligned against the top or the bottom of a picture.

This is the function:

```
private void setAlign(String align) {

    /* Get Preferences */
    SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("prefs", Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();

    editor.putString("align", align);
    editor.commit();

    Log.d("ALIGN", align);

    paramAlign = align;

    FrameLayout.LayoutParams floLP = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
                                            FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                                            FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                                            (align == "TOP") ? Gravity.TOP : Gravity.BOTTOM);

    txtGoal.setLayoutParams(floLP);

    int res = paramAlign == "TOP" ? R.drawable.btn_toolbar_align_top_up : R.drawable.btn_toolbar_align_bottom_up ;
    btnAlign.setImageResource(res);

}
```

Now once the activity is started, this function works fine. However, when I initialize the activity, I call the setAlign() function in the onGlobalLayout method after retrieving the alignment preference.

This is the relevant code:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.personalize);

    /* Get Preferences */
    SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("prefs", Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE);

    paramAlign = prefs.getString("align", "BOTTOM");

    Log.d("ALIGN", paramAlign);

    // Get screen dimensions and initialize preview
    ViewTreeObserver vto = rootView.getViewTreeObserver();
    vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {

        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {

        setAlign(paramAlign);

        ViewTreeObserver obs = rootView.getViewTreeObserver();
            obs.removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
        }

    });

}
```

Now if you notice the logging functions, they both return "TOP" when I start the activity. And the setAlign() function is obviously getting called. Yet, the TextView is aligned at the bottom. This is the XML for the TextView:

```
<TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtGoal"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="10dip"
                android:textColor="@color/color_white"
                android:textSize="8sp"
                android:shadowColor="@color/color_black"
                android:shadowDx="1.2"
                android:shadowDy="1.2"
                android:shadowRadius="1.2"
                />
```

Any idea why the setLayoutParams is not happening when the activity is created? The function is getting fired when the layout is done being drawn so it shouldn't be the issue here. And the XML has no gravity specified to start with.

What am I missing here?

Comment: I also should mention that it does not update the button image either.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I see that the variable txtGoal is not initialized (nor even declared) so I am assuming you did that somewhere else (that is not posted in the question).

The behavior you are encountering is pretty much normal : the function is working only at start-up, and that's because once you change the layout of your text view, you must indicate that so it will be redrawn, by adding the following :

```java
txtGoal.invalidate ();
```

after this :

```
txtGoal.setLayoutParams(floLP);
```

---

EDIT:

<strike>You can also try changing the gravity in a different way:</strike>

```
txtGoal.setGravity ( Gravity.TOP );
```

---

EDIT:

My apologies, what I suggest (the second solution) is wrong, because it changes the gravity of the text inside the text view (and not the gravity of the text view inside the root view).

Please try the following:

Do not try to modify the gravity of your text view using a listener, you can directly apply the gravity you want after setting the content view of your activity (because the text view is thus created). I advise the following:

Apply the new layout to your text view directly (not via the listener) after retrieving the shared preferences.

Your onCreate method should look something similar to this:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.personalize);

    /* Get Preferences */
    SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("prefs", Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE);

    paramAlign = prefs.getString("align", "BOTTOM");

    setAlign(paramAlign);

}
```

---

You should compare two string using the equals method:

Replace that :

```
(align == "TOP")
```

By that

```
align.equals ( "TOP" )
```

And this :

```
paramAlign == "TOP"
```

By this :

```
paramAlign.equals ( "TOP" )
```

Comment: Yes it is indeed initialized somewhere else but kept it short for the sake of this example. I have just tried to add txtGoal.invalidate() after the setLayoutParams but it's still not working.

Comment: What is the layout type of the root view ? (linearlayout, relativelayout ...)

Comment: I have edited my answer, please see the second solution I suggested.

Comment: Not working my friend. I have to say this is really weird. I have two similar functions that get executed as well at the same time and they both work when the dialog is getting created and they both operate on the TextView as well. I have tried changing the order of the functions as well but no difference.

Comment: Alright, little update: After some debugging, I am finding out that when I am calling the setAlign function, R.drawable.btn_toolbar_align_top_up and R.drawable.btn_toolbar_align_bottom_up are resolving to 0. That would probably explain why the button image is not changing. Now why it is resolving to 0 I don't know.

Comment: What do you mean by R.drawable.btn_toolbar_align_top_up and R.drawable.btn_toolbar_align_bottom_up are resolving to 0 ? They are both final (constant) fields of the auto generated R class and cannot be modified. Did you mean that the variable res is assigned the value 0?

Please try the added solution in my answer.

Comment: Please view the reply I just added. For some reason align == "TOP" tested false at startup. But tested true after startup even tho the LogCat told me that align was indeed equal to "TOP" at startup. This is an actual bug in the compiler I believe. I changed my variable to a Boolean since there was only two values this variable could have "TOP" or "BOTTOM".

Comment: Ahhh !! I did not notice that !! This is not a bug, you cannot compare two strings in java using == because the address of the two strings are compared (and not the actual content of the two), you should use the equals method in the following manner: align.equals ( "TOP" )

Comment: So how come the code worked once the activity was initialized?

Comment: OK I just went and read further into this. It all makes sense now. Thanks for the explanation!

Comment: It did work, you compared the address of align and of the string "TOP", and they do not have the same address (they are two distinct string and each is stored in memory in a different address) so the result of align == "TOP" will result false, and thus your text view was located at the bottom.

Take a look at the end of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

So, here is what I found out and what I did to fix my problem.

Apparently the condition

```
align == "TOP"
```

Was not testing true when the activity was started altho the Log dump would tell me that it was in fact true at the time. Now why it did that I have no clue. This seems like a weird bug. That condition tested true once the activity was running.

Since this parameter could only have 2 values, I switched it to a Boolean variable where false is now the equivalent of "BOTTOM" and true the equivalent of "TOP" and it is working perfectly.

This is something that might actually need to be looked into as the condition should of tested true at startup.

** EDIT **

You cannot compare 2 strings in java using the "==" operator. You have to use .equals() instead.